# Send S/MIME encrypted html email with bash

Tags: bash, html-email, smime

How do you send an **encrypted** and **html-formatted** email through the command line? 
 Here is the code I have so far:

```
# Encrypt email with a certificate
openssl cms -encrypt -in "/tmp/email_to_be_sent.html" -out "/tmp/encrypted.txt" -from $SENDER -to $RECEIVER -subject "Test: Encrypted message" -des3 "/tmp/$CERT.pem" 
# Send the encrypted email
cat "/tmp/encrypted.txt" | sendmail -f $SENDER $RECEIVER
```

The generated encrypted email `/tmp/encrypted.txt` is as follow

```
To: recipient@mail.com
From: sender@mail.com
Subject: Test: Encrypted message
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data;name="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

MIIDjAYJKoZIhvcNAQcDoIIDfTCCA3kCAQAxggFZMIIBVQIBADA9MDcxHDAaBgNVBAoME0V1cm9wZWFu
AxAlApQsmjzCwQoonT57JetCp7DHJdHWU1bkLIZWPPBRwa2EB0ZdxOXIvtg7rJavnnbxeTghblM45Pur
A+6BDKJbWvXFyxb...
```

The problem is, once in the recipient inbox and decrypted, the message is not html formatted and html code like `<html><body></body></html>` is still readable inside the message.

Comment: For a full [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it would help if you'd include an example mail that you want to send. And the instructions that you're using to decrypt it as well.

Comment: I of course meant the unencrypted mail. In the encrypted mail there are not <html>-Parts. Are you referring to the fact that the mime-type is not understood by the receiving mail client?

Comment: The message before encryption would be for example 
<html> <body> <p> Test message </p> </body> </html>
And the recipient would receive after decryption (by its mail client)
<html> <body> <p> Test message </p> </body> </html>
Without the html code being interpreted

Comment: Does the HTML-Message get interpreted if you send it via command line without encryption?

Comment: And what Client is trying to interpret the HTML message?

Comment: Tangentially, [the `cat` is useless.](/q/11710552)

Comment: Ok the text should have a header for the HTML code to be interpreted.
Thanks for your help @StefanM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

S/MIME requires the original message to be *enveloped*. This means that the original message is encrypted and this fact and the type of encryption is added to the outer message headers, so the client knows how to handle the message contents.

Because of this, the message headers that define the original message format need to be inside the S/MIME envelope, so the client knows which content type it is after decrypting the message.

The correct way is to extract these headers from the original message, then add them before the original message body. Note that these headers must start on the first line, and that after these headers a blank line is required before the original message body starts.

Headers that should be moved into the enveloped message data are

- MIME-Version (optional)
- Content-Type
- Content-Transfer-Encoding
- Content-Disposition (if exists)

"Moved" means that they should be included in the enveloped message data *and* removed from the outer message headers.

The remaining headers should be left in the envelope message. The `openssl cms -encrypt` command will then add the above headers as required for S/MIME encrypted messages.

### Example

Original message

```
From: someone@somedomain.net
To: recipient@otherdomain.net
Subject: It's a test
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-Custom-Header: Additional data

This is the message text.

Good night.
```

Moved headers before encryption (note the additional blank line)

```
From: someone@somedomain.net
To: recipient@otherdomain.net
Subject: It's a test
X-Custom-Header: Additional data

MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

This is the message text.

Good night.
```

Message after encryption

```
From: someone@somedomain.net
To: recipient@otherdomain.net
Subject: It's a test
X-Custom-Header: Additional data
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data; name="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

MIJ5lAYJKoZIhvcNAQcDoIJ5hTCCeYECAQAxggHZMIIB1QIBADCBvDCBtjEaMBgG
A1UEAwwRc2F2aWduYW5vIENFUlQtaTIxJTAjBgNVBAoMHHNhdmlnbmFubyBzb2Z0
d2FyZSBzb2x1dGlvbnMxHjAcBgNVBAsMFUNlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gU2VydmljZTEL
(more encrypted data removed)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the comments from Stefan leaded me to the solution.
The unencrypted email `/tmp/email_to_be_sent.html` should have a header like this before encryption:

```
To: recipient@mail.com
From: sender@mail.com
Subject: Test: Encrypted message
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<html><body><p> test message </p></body></html>
```

Beware that a newline is needed between the email header and the html code.